# block type="reports/product_viewed" returning the word "empty"

Tags: reports, blocks

we added this block to our side block (block call in block). Mage 1.9.0.1

```
{{block type="reports/product_viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml"}}
```

Now it only return the word "empty"

**question:** Is this normal behavior? and what could we do about it?

thanks, Sean

Comment: can you post the whole code? Where did you put it in?

<reference name="right">
            <block type="reports/product_viewed" before="right.permanent.callout" name="left.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
        </reference>

is my code for example

Comment: Is the `reports/product_viewed.phtml` template modified? Sounds a bit like somebody added an else statement to the template (by default it doesn't output anything unless there are recently viewed products).

Comment: @Thomas Yes we have this code to. This allows us to show the block. The problem is with the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why the text 'empty' appears - we do not know.

The block itself is empty because there is another issue explained here: 
[Column Customer_id in table report_viewed_product_index *always* NULL](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62887/column-customer-id-in-table-report-viewed-product-index-always-null)

The column visitor_id is not recorded and always NULL -> hence there are no recently viewed products to be found when searching the table for a specific user_id ...