# Column Customer_id in table report_viewed_product_index *always* NULL

Tags: database, configuration, reports

we have seen recently that the "Online customers" report is always empty + also the column `customer_id` in table `report_viewed_product_index` is **always NULL**

I know because on our DEV server the column customer_id is always a number (never NULL) ....

What setting in Magento can influence this behavior? Has anyone seen this before?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your problem might be, but I can explain how the values end up in that table.
when a product page is viewed, the event `catalog_controller_product_view` is dispatched.
This event is observed by `Mage_Reports_Model_Event_Observer::catalogProductView`.

This method just instantiates a model and saves record in the table `report_viewed_product_index`

```
 Mage::getModel('reports/product_index_viewed')
        ->setProductId($productId)
        ->save()
        ->calculate();
```

In the _beforeSave method for the model `Mage_Reports_Model_Product_Index_Viewed` the visitor id and customer id are set.

Check `Mage_Reports_Model_Product_Index_Abstract::_beforeSave`.

I wasn't able to reproduce your issue, but I thought that the stacktrace may help you debug the issue.

Comment: I see public function getVisitorId()
     that uses Mage::getSingleton('log/visitor')->getId(); - can it be that we turned of the log model somewhere?

Comment: @snh_nl could be.